# Determining the value of an integral using complex methods

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I need to find the value of the following integral using complex analysis:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(k_1\ x)+\sin(k_2\ x)}{x^2-a^2}\ dx$$  where $k_1, k_2, a$ are real coefficients.

The poles are obviously $\pm a$, so should I apply the residue theorem next?

I get the answer $0$ (which should be correct because the function is even) in a couple of steps, but I never used the condition that the coefficients are real and I'm not sure if my chosen contour of integration is correct.

Any help?

Comment: Since $k_1, k_2\in\mathbb{R}$, the integral is zero as you have found.

Comment: That's what I thought, but my lecturer insists that is not the correct answer. And the integral is obviously supposed to be harder than just that :/

Comment: It is either zero or undefined and if this a complex course, I imagine you are suppose to come up with zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, the integral does not converge near $a$ and $-a$. You can take the [Cauchy Principal Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value), but that is not the same as converging.  The Cauchy Principal Value is $0$, by the way, and that *is* because the integrand is odd.